# Datetimepicker bootstrap not working proberly in asp.net website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I could use some eyes to check what i have done wrong with this code. I have tried to follow an example where i have made to input boxes for check-in and check-out.

It look like this:

```
Check-in
Input box (datetimepicker1)

Check-out
Input box (datetimepicker2)
```

I'm trying to make it so when you pick a date in datepicker1, you can pick an earlier date with the datetimepicker2 form. You have to pick a day at least 1 day ahead.

**My asp code:**

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Check-in     Date:"></asp:Label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker1" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Check-out Date:"></asp:Label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var nowTemp = new Date();
            var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

            var checkin = $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
                onRender: function (date) {
                    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                }
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
                    var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                    checkout.setValue(newDate);
                }
                checkin.hide();
                $('#datetimepicker2')[0].focus();
            }).data('datepicker');
            var checkout = $('#datetimepicker2').datepicker({
                onRender: function (date) {
                    return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                }
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                checkout.hide();
            }).data('datepicker');

        </script>
```

I'm sure that i got the right js files in, because it have worked with some other code before, but it was not that smart, because i don't want any icons, it should only be a text box, and when u click on it, the datetimepicker should open it self.

Hope someone can see what is wrong with this.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what's not working? I don't see a specific problem in your question

Comment: When you click on the testbox, the datetimepicker is not opening.. nothing happens

Comment: What does your browsers js console say? any errors?

Comment: its blank.. if i click control + shift + j, there is no text in the console.

Comment: Could it be, that you don't see a datePicker because you are hiding it? `checkin.hide(); checkout.hide();`

Comment: See the picture i have made.. it dosen't show when you click on the textbox.